# Qt - easiest and fastest way to save (or load) qt variables in (from) file

Tags: qt, file, save, load

I have a ton of qt variables (QString, QMap, QList, and so on) in my application, and I'm looking for the fastest and easiest way to save and load data to and from a file.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QDataStream http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details to serialize your binary datas to save/load from a QIODevice (a QFile for example). See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html for all supported formats including QString, QMap ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually save from a local file, you should use [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html).

You can easily save data like that:

```
QList<QString> list = {"toto", "is it really working ?", "seems nice :)"};
QList<int> listInt = {3, 5, 8};

QList<QString> list2;
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<QString> >("QList<QString>");
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<int> >("QList<int>");

QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Facturo-Pro", this);
settings.setValue("listData", QVariant::fromValue(list));
settings.setValue("listInt", QVariant::fromValue(listInt));
settings.setValue("test", 5);

list2 = settings.value("listData").value<QList<QString>>();

qDebug() << list;
qDebug() << list2;
qDebug() << settings.value("listInt").value<QList<int>>();
qDebug() << settings.value("test").value<int>();
```

Here I created a list of `String` and `int`, as it's special type we need to use `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators` to indicate the type.

Then just create the **QSettings** and **write/read the values**. Note that once you did that one time, a file is created to you don't need the `setValue` anymore